# "PulseEight CEC Adapter - Configuration updated" crash the network

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi, openelec, ethernet-port, networking

I read a lot about this problem but i can figured out how to solve it! I tried to install raspbmc and openElec but i have the same result. When i connect the raspberry, i have a network connection (yellow and green light) but when Xbmc starts and the message "PulseEight CEC Adapter - Configuration updated" pop up the light turn off (only the red are on) and i lost hdmi during a second. The closest thread i found about my problem is this one: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=14273&start=75 . I just remove the d14 diode from my board but i have the same wrong behaviour.